# How do i set my android xml UI on all device screen properly?

Tags: android

which is the best way to show android UI on all device screen properly.
My android UI not showing properly on all android device screen.

Comment: What are you trying?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html ; Long story short, you have different size buckets that you can target, like 4" phones, 7" tabs, 8"+ tabs etc. You have to have different layouts for different screen sizes. Also, please research well before you post here, there is enough info to get from a simple Google search!

Answer (score 0):

Using the LinearLayout’s `android:weightSum` attribute in conjunction with the LinearLayout’s child `android:layout_weight` attribute.

Eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1">

<Button
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="0.5"
  android:text="Click me"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a very specific solution to a very generic question, too specific to really answer the question. The code would compile and run but it doesn't help in sclaing UI. Also, fill_parent was deprecated more than 4 years ago, and hardcoded string and color values should be avoided (especially since FFF is pure white, and already included in the framework).